# Recursive parsing grammar consumes input and fails to parse sequence

Tags: parsing, recursion, f#, fparsec

I'm attempting to write an [Augmented Backus-Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form#Operators) parser. However, I am coming across a Stack Overflow exception whenever I attempt to parse alternatives. Below is an example which triggers the issue:

```ml
#r @"..\packages\FParsec\lib\net40-client\FParsecCS.dll"
#r @"..\packages\FParsec\lib\net40-client\FParsec.dll"
open FParsec

type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, unit>

type Element =
    | Alternates of Element list
    | ParsedString of string

let (pRuleElement, pRuleElementRef) : (Parser<Element> * Parser<Element> ref) = createParserForwardedToRef()

let pString =
    pchar '"' >>. manyCharsTill (noneOf ['"']) (pchar '"')
    |>> ParsedString

let pAlternates : Parser<_> =
    sepBy1 pRuleElement (many (pchar ' ') >>. (pchar '/') >>. many (pchar ' ') )
    |>> Alternates

do pRuleElementRef :=
    choice
        [
            pString
            pAlternates
        ]

"\"0\" / \"1\" / \"2\" / \"3\" / \"4\" / \"5\" / \"6\" / \"7\""
|> run (pRuleElement .>> (skipNewline <|> eof))
```

The issue is easily resolved by simply reordering the `choice` like so:

```ml
do pRuleElementRef :=
    choice
        [
            pAlternates
            pString
        ]
```

However, that then causes a Stack Overflow because it continuously attempts to parse a new sequence of alternatives without consuming input. In addition, that method would then break ABNF precedence:

1. Strings, names formation
2. Comment
3. Value range
4. Repetition
5. Grouping, optional
6. Concatenation
7. Alternative

My question essentially boils down to this: How can I combine parsing of a single element that can be a sequence of elements or a single instance of an element? Please let me know if you require any clarification / additional examples.

Your help is much appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:

I should probably mention that there are various other kinds of groupings as well. A sequence group `(element[s])` and an optional group `[optional element[s]`. Where `element` can be nested groups / optional groups / strings / other element types. Below is an example with sequence group parsing (optional group parsing not included for simplicity):

```ml
#r @"..\packages\FParsec\lib\net40-client\FParsecCS.dll"
#r @"..\packages\FParsec\lib\net40-client\FParsec.dll"
open FParsec

type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, unit>

type Element =
    | Alternates of Element list
    | SequenceGroup of Element list
    | ParsedString of string

let (pRuleElement, pRuleElementRef) : (Parser<Element> * Parser<Element> ref) = createParserForwardedToRef()

let pString =
    pchar '"' >>. manyCharsTill (noneOf ['"']) (pchar '"')
    |>> ParsedString

let pAlternates : Parser<_> =
    pipe2
        (pRuleElement .>> (many (pchar ' ') >>. (pchar '/') >>. many (pchar ' ')))
        (sepBy1 pRuleElement (many (pchar ' ') >>. (pchar '/') >>. many (pchar ' ') ))
        (fun first rest -> first :: rest)
    |>> Alternates

let pSequenceGroup : Parser<_> =
    between (pchar '(') (pchar ')') (sepBy1 pRuleElement (pchar ' '))
    |>> SequenceGroup

do pRuleElementRef :=
    choice
        [
            pAlternates
            pSequenceGroup
            pString
        ]

"\"0\" / ((\"1\" \"2\") / \"2\") / \"3\" / (\"4\" / \"5\") / \"6\" / \"7\""
|> run (pRuleElement .>> (skipNewline <|> eof))
```

If I attempt to parse alternates / sequence groups first, it terminates with a `stack overflow` exception because it then tries to parse alternates repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you run the `pRuleElement` parser on the input, it correctly parses one string, leaving some unconsumed input, but then it fails later outside of the `choice` that would backtrack.

You can run the `pAlternates` parser on the main input, which actually works:

```
"\"0\" / \"1\" / \"2\" / \"3\" / \"4\" / \"5\" / \"6\" / \"7\""
|> run (pAlternates .>> (skipNewline <|> eof))
```

I suspect that you can probably just do this - the `pAlternates` parser works correctly, even on just a single string - it will just return `Alternates` containing a singleton list.

Comment: Hello Tomas, thank you for your response! I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisAltig I think distinguishing between `pString` and `pSequenceGroup` will work just fine, because these two differ in their first character - i.e. the parser will fail if it is not one of these. However, the `pAlternates` is still the one that needs to run at the top level, so that it can consume one thing after another - so I think you will need two parsers - one for anything that can be determined by the first character and another for iterating over that via alternates.

Comment: You read my mind. I had actually just finished programming out a similar solution and was prepping my answer when you commented. I have also come to the conclusion that the ordering doesn't (can't?) match the precedence order listed on the Wikipedia link. Though, I don't think that should matter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the solution was simply not attempting to parse alternatives whilst parsing alternatives in order to avoid an infinite loop resulting in a stack overflow. A working version of the code posted in my question is as follows:

```ml
#r @"..\packages\FParsec\lib\net40-client\FParsecCS.dll"
#r @"..\packages\FParsec\lib\net40-client\FParsec.dll"
open FParsec

type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, unit>

type Element =
    | Alternates of Element list
    | SequenceGroup of Element list
    | ParsedString of string

let (pRuleElement, pRuleElementRef) : (Parser<Element> * Parser<Element> ref) = createParserForwardedToRef()
let (pNotAlternatives, pNotAlternativesRef) : (Parser<Element> * Parser<Element> ref) = createParserForwardedToRef()

let pString =
    pchar '"' >>. manyCharsTill (noneOf ['"']) (pchar '"')
    |>> ParsedString

let pAlternates : Parser<_> =
    pipe2
        (pNotAlternatives .>>? (many (pchar ' ') >>? (pchar '/') >>. many (pchar ' ')))
        (sepBy1 pNotAlternatives (many (pchar ' ') >>? (pchar '/') >>. many (pchar ' ') ))
        (fun first rest -> first :: rest)
    |>> Alternates

let pSequenceGroup : Parser<_> =
    between (pchar '(') (pchar ')') (sepBy1 pRuleElement (pchar ' '))
    |>> SequenceGroup

do pRuleElementRef :=
    choice
        [
            pAlternates
            pSequenceGroup
            pString
        ]

do pNotAlternativesRef :=
    choice
        [
            pSequenceGroup
            pString
        ]

"\"0\" / (\"1\" \"2\") / \"3\" / (\"4\" / \"5\") / \"6\" / \"7\""
|> run (pRuleElement .>> (skipNewline <|> eof))
```

In addition to the addition of `pNotAlternatives` I also modified it so that it would backtrack when failing to parse the alternative separator `/` which allows it to proceed after "realizing" that it wasn't a list of alternatives after all.